# The "CSPack" task was not given a value for the required parameter "ServiceDefinitionFile"

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-devops

I am doing a PoC over the new Visual Studio Online build system, I managed to setup a build and run the unit tests for my project but when I try to build the ccproj in order to deploy it in Azure I get this error:

```
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.5\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(2930,5): Error MSB4044: The "CSPack" task was not given a value for the required parameter "ServiceDefinitionFile".
```

It is quite strange I just took the template for Deployment and changed the location of the ccproj:

[image]

I googled it and seems like a couple of fellows have same issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue and resolve it by adding "/p:OutputPath=bin\" in "MSBuild Arguments" for Visual Studio Build(ccproj) step.

Following is the arguments in my build definition:

```
/t:Publish /p:TargetProfile=$(targetProfile) /p:DebugType=None /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PublishDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:OutputPath=bin\
```